# Extract text portion with RegEx

Tags: regex

I am currently struggling with a RegEx rule to extract a text portion (2 characters) from a string.

The string has a following format:

```
"ML6G 100.00 TEST"
```

What I want to extract here is the L6 (this can change but the length will always be 2 characters) and I know that the characters before the L6 can vary in length (1,2,3,4,5 characters long)

So the string could look something like this:

"MMMMML6G 132.00 CBT" -> here I want to extract L6 as well but again the characters before can vary in length (1,2,3,4,5 characters long).

I know I can extract/match text with the following expression:

```
^.{0,2}
```

But I don't know how can I extract something after (1 or 2 or... or 5 characters)

Comment: What can follow the L6? One character and a space? Or other things as well?

Comment: M+(.{2})   will do for you

Comment: Try `^\S{1,5}(\S{2})` and get the contents of the first capturing group, see https://regex101.com/r/nK3dK2/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but that doesn't capture `L6` for `ML6G 100.00 TEST`

Comment: That means the question is a bit incorrect. The pattern meets the requirement, but not the example.

Comment: I agree to some extent. The OP isn't clear about what is the requirement. (The requirement in the OP, or the requirement in [their comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037187/extract-text-portion-with-regex#comment65424232_39037251))

Comment: Now, @user2606751, explain how *`KJSHW7P 100.00 TEST` (here I need to extract 7P)* and *`OLPU6P 899.0 LKO` (I want to extract U6)* are different? Why in the first example, the alphanum chars you need are before the space, and in the 2nd, they are before the last alphanum char that is before space? **What are the specs**?

Comment: Oh my, I have tried [`^(?|\S{1,5}?(\S{2})G|\S{1,5}(\S{2}))`](https://regex101.com/r/nS5bH4/1) - does the letter `G` make the whole difference?

Comment: Closing as completely obscure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will be only several 'M' before and always a 'G' after, I would take following regex:

```
[M]+(.{2,2})G
```

*Explanation*

[M]+ matches 1 or more 'M'

(.{2,2}) matches any character with a length of exactly 2 returning these characters in a sperate group.

'G' matches a 'G' ;-)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. Actually I want to extract two characters after the first 1,2,3,4 or 5 characters. 

So the string can contain:

XXXL6P 100.00 TEST (here I need to extract 6P)

or the string can be 

KJSHW7P 100.00 TEST (here I need to extract 7P)

Comment: To write a regex expression, we have to find out something specific we can match. Assuming that there are 1 - 5 characters before and only 1 character after followed by a blank, you could take ^[A-Z]{1,5}([A-Z1-9]{2,2})[A-Z]{1,1}\w

Comment: @user2606751, why do you say `XXXL6P 100.00 TEST` should give `6P`, while in the question you say `ML6G 100.00 TEST` should give `L6`. Why is that last not `6G`? What is the logic to choose the two characters? When to take the last two of the word, leave the last character out?

Answer (score 1):

Use a back reference to consume repeated chars at the start, then capture the next 2 chars:

```
^(.)\1*(..)
```

This captures the characters you want, eg `L6`, in group 2.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.

Comment: There can be any character, it doesn't have to be MMMMM. 
So I want to extract 2 characters after either the first 1,2,3,4 or 5 characters.

Comment: So the "M" character will repeat? What about following character "G" - it is always there then a space, or you don't care what follows?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the first break (space) and backtrace 2 positions from the last character of the first segment.

```
(?=(.{2}).\s).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/fV7vG3/1

Comment: No, that won't work: *Actually I want to extract two characters after the first 1,2,3,4 or 5 characters. So the string can contain: XXXL6P 100.00 TEST (here I need to extract 6P) or the string can be KJSHW7P 100.00 TEST (here I need to extract 7P)*

Comment: Ah, I see... Where are you reading this? This regex is fine for the OP

Comment: Why the look ahead? Just `(..)\s.*`